# Newton's Law of Cooling, but not give t=0 temperature?

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

I encountered this Newton's Law of Cooling questions in my textbook and usually it gives the temperature when t = 0, but this time it didn't, which is giving me a hard time.

It says exactly as follows,

> A hot object is placed in a room whose temperature is 80F.  After 1 minute, the temperature of the object is 160F and its rate of change of temperature is 22F per minute.  Find the initial temperature of the object.

Here is my attempt,

> dT/dt = k (t - 80)
>
> dT(1/(T-80) = dt k
>
> ln (T-80) = kt +c
>
> T = ce^(kt) + 80
>
> T prime = [ce^(tk)]/k

So, it says

> T(1) = 160 F
>
> T prime(1) = 22 F/min

Which gives me,

> 160 = ce^k + 80
>
> 22 = (ce^k)/k

I solved for c in the second eq.

> 22k/e^k = c

Plug in the first eq.

> 160 = (22k/e^k) * e^k + 80
>
> 80 = 22k
>
> k = 80/22

So I have k now, now I solve for c,

> 160 = ce^(80/22) + 80
>
> c = 80/e^(80/22)

This all seems correct to me but, BUT when I test it out on my calculator, the values it gives seems way too large.

The textbook has no solution for even numbers, so I am unable to compare answers.

Can you guys spot my mistake...?

Comment: Of course, there should have been a constant in your third equation. It magically appeared in the next equation ...

Answer (score 3):

Check your T prime!

(Sorry, this would work better as a comment, but I need one upvote for that)

Comment: OMG! did i just integrate T prime instead of differentiate?!

Comment: I believe you did (well, without the +c). Happens to the best of us! Thanks for the upvote.